# Send notification of new sharepoint news by mail automatically

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

I have a SP modern Team site with "News" web part on the main page. I want to notify users via email when news are posted.

It is possible to send a digest to email [manually](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-and-send-a-news-digest-42efc3c6-605f-4a9a-85d5-1f9ff46019bf).

However, I want to automate it.

I tried using Power Automate. The flow was to send an email on creating a new page (the news are basically pages), but it didn't fulfill my needs:
1)i couldn't put the body of the page in an email, only the subject and hyperlink to the page;
2)the page is created instantly after hitting "create post" button (before any editing). Means the email also sends instantly without any content.

Could you guys tell me the way i can achieve what i need?